# Firebase Remote Config with Chinese characters

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-remote-config

Remote Config getString() return different result between version 18.0.0 and version 19.0.0.

I have tried setting

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8
```

in the `gradle.properties`

I also tried setting

```
compileOptions {
    encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

in `build.gradle`

below is the code snippet

```
fun getRemoteString(key: String) {
    val wording = FirebaseRemoteConfig.getInstance().getString(key) 
    Log.d(javaClass.simpleName, "wording= $wording")
    return wording
}
```

I expected Firebase Remote Config return `登入閱讀,` just like what 18.0.0 returned
but now it returns `ç»å¥é±è®,` for 19.0.0

Is there any settings I need to config?

Thanks.

Comment: Please file a bug report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, I've filed a bug report, but I'm sorry that I forgot to attach this stackoverflow link. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I face the same issue.. 
as a temp solution Im converting the ISO_8859_1 String to UTF-8

```
newValue = new String(wording.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
```

Comment: Thanks. I've also tried this workaround. However, I am wondering if it is always ISO-8859-1 or it would be other encoding?

Comment: Firebase developer replied that it is a known bug and it will be fixed in next release. I'll mark @benash 's answer as correct since it temporarily solves my problem for now.

Comment: as i can see in my app, this solution is no longer needed

Comment: Yes, version 19.0.1 fixed the problem.